# SQL Compilation error while loading CSV file from S3 to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

we are facing below issue while loading csv file from S3 to Snowflake.

> SQL Compilation error: Insert column value list does not match column list expecting 7 but got 6

we have tried removing the column from table and tried again but this time it is showing `expecting 6 but got 5`

below are the the commands that we have used for stage creation and copy command.

```sql
create or replace stage mystage
url='s3://test/test'
STORAGE_INTEGRATION = test_int
file_format = (type = csv FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'  COMPRESSION=GZIP);


copy into mytable
from  @mystage
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE;
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"' COMPRESSION=GZIP error_on_column_count_mismatch=false TRIM_SPACE=TRUE NULL_IF=(''))
FORCE = TRUE
ON_ERROR = Continue
PURGE=TRUE;
```

Comment: pls show your column names/schema

Comment: Thanks Mitch for your reply, due to security reasons we are not able to display the object names. :)

Comment: then I doubt you'll be getting much help.

Comment: do you want to see the column names and their datatypes in the table ?

Comment: You have a semicolumn (;) in the middle of your COPY INTO command, is it normal ?
... MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE; FILE_FORMAT = ...

Comment: sorry , it is not there by mistake ; given, now removed it
`copy into mytable
from  @mystage
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"' COMPRESSION=GZIP error_on_column_count_mismatch=false TRIM_SPACE=TRUE NULL_IF=(''))
FORCE = TRUE
ON_ERROR = Continue
PURGE=TRUE;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME for the CSV files, this is why you get this error.

This copy option is supported for the following data formats:

- JSON
- Avro
- ORC
- Parquet

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Comment: Thank you Atil. issue got resolved after removing this option MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME